# Maximum number of requests for SkyDrive?

Tags: request, onedrive

What is the Maximum number of requests for SkyDrive?

I need the request per second and the request per day.

For example :  for GDrive the Maximum number of requests per second is 10 QPS. Maximum number of requests per day is 10,000,000 QPD across the account.